# Checked radio button style sibling label

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I working on some functionality at the moment, that mask a radio input to look like coloured square, when a radio is selected the sibling label background should change colour, what is happening though is whatever radio button I check, the first label always changes colour, here is my fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/heZBT/3622/

I thought this code would suffice to make the correct label change,

```
input:checked + label {
   background:yellow;
}
```

everything I try will only ever make the first radio sibling label go yellow when any radio is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same `id` and `for` attributes for your labels/buttons. Change them up and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/bfehyv2a/